# Selenium grid: how to keep sessions until closed manually

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

Selenium grid: how to keep sessions until closed manually?

```
services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    shm_size: '2gb'
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "7900:7900"
```

When a test fails, I need to check the running session on http://localhost:7900 to see what's wrong. After a while, the session is gone. How to keep the session forever until I close the browser http://localhost:7900 manually?